# Disable pinch-to-zoom in iOS 10 in Cordova/Phonegap app

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview, pinchzoom, cordova-ios

I have a mobile app build with phonegap (cordova) and the app is live on app store, but this new feature of iOS10 beta:

> To improve accessibility on websites in Safari, users can now **pinch-to-zoom** even when a website sets **user-scalable=no** in the viewport.

make the app zoomable and it totally broke the design of the app when zoomed.

Maybe this is a feature for websites on mobile (or not), but I want to be able to disable this for a hybrid mobile app

This is how the `viewport` looks like in `index.html`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```

Is there a known solution to resolve this problem for the new iOS that will be released soon?

I am using `WkWebView` and

```
<engine name="ios" spec="~3.9.2" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
```

**UPDATE**

I updated phonegap to version 6.3.0 and ios platform version to 4.1.1 and I have the same error.

Answer (score 6):

use `user-scalable=no` as the following code :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

Comment: I already use `user-scalable=no`, but the new ios10 ignore this tag. The problem is only on ios10.

Comment: install latest cordova and try again

Comment: I upgraded phonegap to 6.3.0 and ios platform engine to 4.1.1 and I have the same error. So this doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Seems that "maximum-scale=1" also needs to be removed in order to pinch and zoom.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
document.addEventListener('gesturestart', (event) => { event.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

Answer found:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/1054

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for iOS 10+

```
// stop ios bounce and zoom 
document.ontouchmove = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
};
```

This will stop move events reaching the root element/browser

Comment: does not work, testing on ios13